# Confusion about C pointers

Tags: c, function, pointers, dereference, pointer-to-pointer

I am sending this message to clear my confusion that I could not manage and handle.

The foo1 function code should work. I am giving the code details for you.

When I run the code, the result is a segmentation error at line 12. Then I made a little change in foo2 in different syntax notation. foo2 is working. But I want to learn more deeply how pointers work. Which kind of error can cause this error. If I don't use line 12 everything looks fine. What would be the main reason for this issue. Could you please assist me?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int foo1(char ***BufferArray,char *item,int idx);
int foo2(char ***BufferArray,char *item,int idx);
int main(){
    char **ptr=malloc(sizeof(char*)*3);
    char a[]="hello0";
    char b[]="hello1";
    char c[]="hello2";
    foo1(&ptr,a,0);
    //foo1(&ptr,b,1);//Exception has occurred. Segmentation fault //line 12
    printf("[%s]",*(ptr+0));
    printf("[%s]",*(ptr+1));
    getchar();
    return(0);
}

int foo1(char ***BufferArray,char *item,int idx){
    int n;
    n=1;
    **(BufferArray+idx)=malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(item));
    strcpy(**(BufferArray+idx),item);
    return(0);
}

int foo2(char ***BufferArray,char *item,int idx){
    int n;
    char **temp=*BufferArray;
    *(temp+idx)=malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(item));
    strcpy(*(temp+idx),item);
    *BufferArray=temp;
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Both functions are wrong.: `sizeof(char)*strlen(item)` make that `strlen(item)+1`

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use array notation: `*(temp+idx)` => `temp[idx]`

Comment: Do yourself another favor and do not add unnecessary levels of indirection. There is no need to use type `char ***` for the `BufferArray` parameter when `char **` will do fine. You would only need to use `char ***` if you plan to reallocate the memory the `char **` pointer points to within the function.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing to the function `foo1`

```
foo1(&ptr,b,1);
```

a pointer to the pointer `ptr` defined like

```
char **ptr=malloc(sizeof(char*)*3);
```

So to access the pointer within the function you may use an expression  either like `*BufferArray` or like `*( BufferArray + 0 )` or like BufferArray[0].

In the function `foo2` you are in fact using one of these expressions

```
char **temp=*BufferArray;
```

An expression like that `*(BufferArray+idx)` used in the function `foo1` where the variable `idx` is greater than `0` tries to access memory outside the passed pointer that invokes undefined behavior when the expression is further dereferenced.

Pay attention to that strings contain trailing zero character `'\0'`. You need to reserve memory also to it if you are going to copy a string in the allocated memory. That is you need to write for example

```
*(temp+idx)=malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(item) + 1);
                                             ^^^                  
strcpy(*(temp+idx),item);
```

Using `sizeof( char )` in the call of `malloc` is redundant and makes the line kess readable. Instead you could write simply

```
*(temp+idx)=malloc( strlen(item) + 1 );
```

Comment: It doesn't make any difference really since `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition, but `malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(item) + 1)` should logically be `malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(item) + 1))` or `malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(item) + sizeof(char));`.

Comment: @IanAbbott Your comment does not make sense. The problem is that the size of the allocated memory shall be one greater than in the initial code.  Using sizeof( char ) is entirely redundant. It is enpugh to write malloc(strlen(item) + 1)

Comment: My comment was really just pointing out a possible *coding style* issue of mixing `sizeof(char)` and `1` in the same expression where the `1` is standing in for `sizeof(char)`. For comparison, `malloc(sizeof(wchar_t)*wcslen(witem) + 1)` would of course be an actual error if the intention is to allocate sufficient extra space for a wide null terminator.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem in `foo1()` is lack of consideration of operator precedence. `**(BufferArray+idx)` should be `*(*BufferArray)+idx)`. This could also be written `*(BufferArray[0]+idx)` or `(*BufferArray)[idx]` or `BufferArray[0][idx]`.

The original `**(BufferArray+idx)` is equivalent to `*BufferArray[idx]` (i.e. `*(BufferArray[idx])`) or `BufferArray[idx][0]`. In the call `foo1(&ptr,b,1)`, `BufferArray` points to the `char **ptr` variable in `main()` and `idx` is 1. `BufferArray+idx` points to the location just past the end of the `ptr` variable itself. The pointer value is valid because pointing just past the end of a variable is allowed, but dereferencing that pointer results in *undefined behavior* (UB) in the same way that accessing an element just past the end of an array results in UB.

---

As pointed out by others, the call `*(temp+idx)=malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(item));` does not allocate room to store a null terminator character at the end of the string, so the subsequent call `strcpy(*(temp+idx),item);` writes past the end of the allocated memory (`strcpy(a,b)` copies `strlen(b)+1` characters, including the null terminator character), resulting in UB.